# Parameter Value: "Get values from a query" not working on host

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm having problems when using the option "Get values from a query" in my Parameter settings.

[image]

On the server everything works like a charm.

[image]

But when I deploy and then launch the report on my hosting, I get an error message:

[image]

If I use the option: "None", then **everything** works fine.
I've placed a test Tablix, to see the result of the dataset on the host, and also this causes no problem.

[image]

So the issue is only with the "Get values from a query" section AND only on the hosting.

Anybody got an idea?
EDIT: I turned EnableRemoteErrors on, as requested by the errormessage, but no additional info is given.

Answer (score 0):

The detail of the error is in the SSRS log file located at -->

```
<SSSRS_INSTALL_DIR>\Report Server\Log Files.
```

That is where I would go. Based how you describe the dataset driving the parameters works but not when given a value then I would expect this to be a parameter mismatch or missing parameter. Make sure that you are feeding the dataset the parameters you think you are. Also, if you don't allow nulls then make sure you are supplying a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You said, you placed a tablix on the report showing the results of the `YearsDOW` dataset and this fails. If this also fails when you set your available values to 'None' then we can assume, as the error states, that the issue was with executing the query itself, not your report design.

As this seems to work when you run it from your local machine in development but fails when run from the server I would suspect it's an authentication/permissions issue.

Check the credentials on the **datasource** in your development environment and compare these to the SSRS server's version of the datasource. Remember, by default datasources do not get overwritten so it maybe that you deployed the datasource initially with one set of credentials then then changed them in your development environment.

If this is the case and the datasource is not used for other reports on the server, then you can either change the project properties to overwrite datasources but personally I prefer to delete the datasource from the server and then redeploy, that way future changes won't affect the servers version unintentionally.

If the datasource is used in other reports without problems then you could just rename the datasource to something unique so it will get redeployed under the new name and your report will point to that new version.